# Trimming text values for temporary storage as Variable

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want to create a variable based on partial text from a string. The variable will be used in the same test Spec

The element is located thus:

```
 .//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4
```

The output being:

"Your booking reference is: DBM039444."

I need to retrieve DBM039444 or whichever number is generated.

I've tried using the old Excel-type of Left() and Right() but without much success.

Please can anyone offer the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use split for this and divide the string at the first occurrence of ": " which should always immediately precede the booking ref number

**async/await**

```
let eleText = await element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText();

//splits the string when it finds ": " which should occur only once
let bookingRef = eleText.split(": ")[1];
console.log(bookingRef)
```

**Control Flow**

```
element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4"))
    .getText().then(eleTxt => {
        let bookingRef = eleText.split(": ")[1];
        console.log(bookingRef)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand that it will be 'DBM' followed by a number, you could retrieve the entire string, and then do a `string.replace(/\D/g, '');` <-- that would return just the number.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely un-flexible selector (`.//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h`). Find this tag more dynamically so that you don't have to fix this if the page under test ever changes. Also, the following change would give you an alternative answer.

Since your post does not mention what programming language your test is in, I am writing this answer in C#:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
...
string javascriptCommand = @"
    var text = 'Your booking reference is:';
    var result = $(`h4:contains('${text}')`).text();
    return result.replace(text, '');
";
string referenceId = driver.ExecuteJavascript<string>(javascriptCommand).Trim();
```

Comment: Thanks - We use JScript (sorry for not mentioning) but I think I can 'translate'. The selector was purely and exemplar- we tend to use PageObjects wherever possible.